# SqlKata how to insert many value from a list

Tags: asp.net-core

How can I execute an insertmany using sqlkata? I have a list and I want to perform an insertmany

```
public async Task<TimeSpan> AddBulk(List<Transaction> transactions)
{
        var cols = new[] { "Id", "Name", "Description", "Quantity", "AddedOn", "ModifiedOn" };
        Start = DateTime.Now;

        try
        {
            var result = await _db.Query("Transaction").InsertAsync(cols, new[] { transactions });
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
        }
        
        TimeSpan = DateTime.Now - Start;
        return TimeSpan;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
var result = _db.Query("Transaction").AsInsert(cols, transactions);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the list of your data to `List<object[]>` then try to insert multiple records like this:

```
        var cols = new[] {
            "YourField1",
            "YourField2" ,
            "YourField3"
        };

        var data = new List<object[]>();
        foreach (var item in YourListObject)
        {
            data.Add(new object[]
            {
                item.YourField1,
                item.YourField2,
                item.YourField3
            });

        }

        var affectedRows = _db.Query(typeof(Permission).Name)
            .Insert(cols, p);
```